# How to get previous month number in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

How to get Previous Month number  and Month before Previous Month number in SQLite,

I am using `strftime('%m','now')` for getting current month number but not finding anything to extract previous month number, how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`date` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the previous month:

```
SELECT strftime('%m', date('now','start of month','-1 month'));
SELECT strftime('%m', date('now','start of month','-2 month'));
```

It's fairly self explanatory:  This uses the date function to get the first day of the current month (to prevent issues on the last days of a month with more days than the previous month), then subtract 1 or 2 months.  Then use `strftime` to pull out just the month number.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite has a modulo operator (%), so if `month` is the current month number, you can calculate:

```sql
previous_month = (month - 2) % 12 + 1
month_before_previous = (month - 3) % 12 + 1
```